# level=fatal msg="x509: cannot validate certificate for <PostgreSQL host ip> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs"

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm getting the error in docker logs as "level=fatal msg="x509: cannot validate certificate for  because it doesn't contain any IP SANs"

and the docker compose file is given below

```
    ...
    services:
    test:
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - '127.0.0.1:8080:8080'
    image: gcr.io/test/test.2.0.7
    environment:
    - ENV_TYPE=dev
    - AUTH0_AUD=abcdfgrthwjsjxsjxsx
    - AUTH0_ISS=https://testus.auth0.com/
    - PG_HOSTNAME=<ip address of Postgresql>
    - PG_PORT=5432
    - PG_USER=Test
    - PG_PASSWORD=test123
    - PG_DB_NAME=test_db
    - VAULT_ID=hello
    - APP_BUFFER_SIZE_DB_READ=25000
    - APP_BUFFER_SIZE_DB_WRITE=25000
    - APP_SSL_MODE=True
    - NODE_ADDR=wss://test.example.net/rpc
    - SECRET_SEED=0x9089009fcb34b31da88c69aca70836d4c17c4d0e827fa1864
    - ACTIVATION_DEST_BUCKET=test-bucket
```

and the postgressql configuration using terraform is

```
    resource "google_sql_database_instance" "pg_instance" {
        name = "test-pg-${random_id.postfix.hex}"
        database_version = "POSTGRES_13"
        region = var.gcp_region
        project = var.gcp_project
        deletion_protection = false
        settings {
        tier = var.db_tier
         availability_type = var.db_avialability_type  
         disk_autoresize = true
         disk_autoresize_limit = var.db_autoresize_limit
          disk_type = "PD_SSD"
         disk_size = var.db_disk_size
         maintenance_window {
          day  = "7"  # sunday
          hour = "3" # 3am
          }

             backup_configuration {
               backup_retention_settings {
                retained_backups = var.retained_backups
                retention_unit = "COUNT"
             }
          }

              ip_configuration {
              ipv4_enabled = true
              require_ssl = false
              #allocated_ip_range = "10.0.0.0/24"
              authorized_networks {
              value = "0.0.0.0/0"
           }

          and manually tried with client ssl keys but not worked and same error came
```

...

Comment: Verify what the certificate CN is. Normally it is the Cloud SQL instance name. That means you must disable certificate verification or use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy (recommended).

Comment: Thank you very replying ,for Same application in Azure , I used CA_CERT_PATH_URL=https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem
in docker compose file and it worked. likewise any crt.pem is available for gcp

Comment: Then there is something missing in your question. Cloud SQL is accessed by IP address. Cloud SQL certificates do not contain the IP address, which means certificate validation will fail when connecting using TLS.